# Construction of sequences in Topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the following statement: the limit of any sequence in $A$ belongs to $A$ if and only if $A$ is closed.
I have already proven that if $A$ is closed the limit of any sequence must be in $A$.

Now for the converse, I was thinking about constructing a sequence for every point $p$ in the closure of $A$, (denoted $\overline{A}$) so that the limit is $p$. Then of course we would have that $\overline{A} \subset A$, and it would be proven.

Some definitions: $X$ is a topological space and Hausdorff, $A$ is a subset of $X$. The closure of $A$ is defined as $\overline{A}=\{ p \in X \mid U \cap A \neq \emptyset\, \ \text{for every open set} \ U  \ \text{containing} \ p \}$

My construction:

> Given a arbitrary point $p \in \overline{A}$, and an open neighborhood $V^p$ of $p$. By definition we have that $V^p \cap A \neq  \emptyset$ so we can choose an arbitrary $x \in V^p$. And we define  $x_n$ as any point in $V^p_n$ so that $ V^p_n \subset V^p_{n-1}$ and $x_{n-1} \notin V^p_{n}$. And for any set containing $V^p$ we can set $x_n$ the constant series equal to $x$.

Now we have that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $p$ by definition. And thus $p$ must be in $A$ by assumption so that means $A=\overline{A}$ and thus closed.

My question:

> My construction feels somewhat vague and I am not sure if i can make those choices, I made. Also is $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ even well defined? It feels right, but I am unsure. in short does this work?

Comment: What you're asking is not true for any topological space. it is true however for metric space. hence you should precise what spaces you're considering.

Comment: Hausdorff Spaces as mentioned. Is that not enought to be true ?

Comment: You need a generalization of sequence to get equivalence. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Closed_sets_and_closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done even in a compact Hausdorff space. Let $X$ be the ordinal $\omega_1+1=\omega_1\cup \{\omega_1\}$ with the $\in$-order topology. Let $A=\omega_1.$ Any limit-point of any countable sequence of members of $A$ is a member of $A.$ But $A$ is not closed, as the point $\omega_1$ belongs to $\overline A\setminus A.$

The tightness $t(X)$ of a space $X$ is the least infinite cardinal $k$ such that whenever $A\subseteq X$ and $p\in \overline A,$ there exists $B\subseteq A$ with $|B|\le k$ and $p\in\overline B.$ (Note $B$ need not be an infinite set.) There is no universal upper bound on $t(X)$ even for compact Hausdorff spaces.

Another example: The non-compact Hausdorff space $X=\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ with the box topology. A base (basis) for the box topology on $X$ is the collection of all $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$ where each $U_n$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R.$

Let $\dot 0=(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ where every $x_n=0.$

Let $X^+=\{(y_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in X: \forall n\in\Bbb N\,(y_n>0)\}.$

If $U$ is any nbhd of $\dot 0,$ then there is a basic open set $V=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n$ with $p\in V\subset U.$ And for each $n$ there must exist $r_n\in\Bbb R^+$ with $(-r_n,r_n)\subset U_n$ (because $\dot 0\in \prod_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n \,).$

Now $(r_n/2)_{n\in\Bbb N}\in U\cap X^+.$ Therefore $\dot 0\in\overline {X^+}.$

But if $S=\{y(j):j\in\Bbb N\}$ is any countable subset of $X^+,$ then let $y(j)=(y_{j,n})_{n\in \Bbb N}.$ Now let $z_n=\frac {1}{2}y_{n,n}$ for each $n.$ Then $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}(-z_n,z_n),$ which is a nbhd of $\dot 0$, is disjoint from $S$. So $\dot 0\not\in\overline S.$

Comment: A surprising non-result is that it is still unknown whether the box topology on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ is normal ($T_4$) or not.

Comment: So in order to work for  topological space $X$ has to be metrizable? or is there a weaker asumption?

Comment: @Xero33 . Metric spaces belong to a larger class called sequential spaces, which are in an even larger class of the spaces of tightness $\aleph_0$... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space